# For each Iteration through Linq

Tags: linq, foreach, iterator

I am new to linq and I am trying to learn it in real time. Following is a code from vb.net from one of my apps:

```
    For Each k As BSPLib.ContactLib.Contact In data_org
        data.Add(k.prime)
    Next
```

Where data and data_org are Observable collections of type Contact.Prime and Contact class respectively.
Is it possible to do the above with a linq query like below

```
data = From k As BSPLib.ContactLib.Contact In data_org Select k.prime
```

But the above is giving the following error at runtime:

```
Unable to cast object of type WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[BSPLib.ContactLib.Contact,BSPLib.ContactLib.ContactPrime]' to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[BSPLib.ContactLib.ContactPrime]'.
```

Could you please guide me.  Thank you.

Comment: Final solution per answers is to use it this way: data = New System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of BSPLib.ContactLib.ContactPrime)(From k As BSPLib.ContactLib.Contact In data_org Select k.prime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` variable is declared as an `ObservableCollection`.  There are no implicit conversions from enumerables to that.  You'll have to create an instance of an `ObservableCollection` with those contents.  Fortunately you could just pass it into the constructor.

```
Dim query = From k As BSPLib.ContactLib.Contact In data_org Select k.prime
data = New ObservableCollection(Of ContactPrime)(query)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked, also came to know that this sort of constructors are also there, i.e. braces after braces.  Could you point out where I can find an article for such type.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well the [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) is a generic class.  So the first set of parentheses denotes the type of objects the collection holds.  The second set of parentheses is the actual arguments to the constructor.  You'll generally need to use two sets of parentheses when dealing with anything generic from classes and interfaces to generic methods as well.

Comment: Thank you that adds to my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are selecting k.prime from your linq query.

The result of your query will be type of k.prime.

Hence when you try to cast in the foreach

foreach k as BSPLib.ContactLib.Contact in data_org is not valid since k is of typeof(k.prime)

In your code above you must use

data = From k As BSPLib.ContactLib.Contact In data_org **Select k**

Comment: Thank you.  However my question is to get the k.prime objects only.